# Where do I find the XeLaTeX engine on TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, xepersian

I want to type a text in persian. Does texstudio support xelatex? If yes where  can i find it?
this is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\begin{document}
\centerline{به نام خداوند بخشندهٔ مهربان}

سلام

این یک مثال ساده با زی‌پرشین است. 

به همین سادگی.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, it in the tools menu.

Comment: I see no such name as xelatex on tools menu???!!

Comment: Did you check all submenus?

Comment: Yes please look at the photo below

Comment: If your texstudio is uptodate: Go to the options of texstudio, enable the extended options, and then in the entry "menu" enable the additional commands.

Comment: Hi ans welcome, this is not a very helpful information, please add a [short but compilable test case](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) along with the log-file to the question above.

Comment: i compiled it using xelatex but i keep getting this error:Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H <return>.

Comment: Can u please tell me what should i do?

Comment: Opten the option, go to commands, change the first line to `xelatex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`. Instead of `pdflatex`, you need to select `latex` in the tools menu.

Comment: still no success .i added my code above please tell me if theres sth wrong with it.

Comment: Different question come to my mind: 1) have you used LaTeX before? if the basics are missing, you cannot give clear response. This seems to be the case right now. 2) Did you manage to run XeLaTeX on a simple *Hello world* document? 3) Your code misses the definition of a persian font, this is what XeLaTeX is telling me in plain english. Downloading a font, and set this font up for usage, everything is working just fine.

Comment: `\centerline` should not be used in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Depending on your precise needs there are different options:

- If you want to only run XeLaTeX explicitly from time to time, use `Tools -> Commands -> XeLaTeX`. You may assign a shortcut in the options.
- If you want to modify the default build configuration (i.e. the compiler for `Tools -> Build / Build & View`) then change `Options -> Build -> Default Compiler`.
- If you want to modify the build configuration only for this file, include the "magic comment" `% !TeX program = xelatex` at the top if your file. See [the manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION_TEXCOM) for more information on magic comments.

Comment: Is there a way to run this command from GUI **xelatex filename.tex --shell-escape**. @TimHoffmann