# Calibri font and others format requirements

Tags: fonts, margins, page-numbering, line-spacing, apa-style

I'm writing my Master's thesis and I have to meet certain requirements:

1. Body text: Calibri font, 12 points.
2. Margins: Top, bottom, and right: 2.5 cm; Left: 3.5 cm. --> *Seems that \geometry will work fine*
3. Multiple 1.2-point line spacing; 6-point spacing between paragraphs. --> *\linespread ,maybe?*
4. Pagination: Page numbers centered at the bottom of the page; Calibri 10 points. --> *No idea.*
5. Citation system and all others APA rules (http://www.apastyle.org/learn/tutorials/basics-tutorial.aspx). --> *I will cry with this in the future...*
6. Footnotes: When necessary, Calibri 10 points.

About the worst issue, the font: when I try to compile with Calibri, I get an error message. In many similar posts, they mention LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX which I have no idea of what they exactly are (but I use TexStudio and it seems to have them, despite not knowing what they are or how do they work). What can I do?

**UPDATE.**

1. Seems fixed. Just added `% !TeX program = xelatex` as first line. *Most of my work its done with PDFLatex, so I'm still compiling with that as default untill I learn about differences between them (and LuaLaTex) to choose other as main compiler.*
2. Done. The `geometry` package works fine.
3. Not sure if I made it or not. I added the command, but not sure the output to be 6pt.
4. Got numbering centered, but not at Calibri 10pt.
5. I only tried to add hanging indent by the moment. Too many rules to check at once.
6. Haven't tried yet. I usually avoid footnotes, so I don't even know how to make them.

Here the a sample code

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\fontsize{10}{12} \centering\thepage}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.2}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt} 
\setlength{\parindent}{1.27cm}


\section{Sección 1.}

\lipsum[1-25]

\section{Sección 2.}

\lipsum[26-30]

\subsection{Checking secctions.}

\lipsum[30-40]

\end{document}
```

and here the output it's producing.[image: My compiled file]

Comment: I personally would not recommend typesetting long text sections with a sans-serif font such as Calibri, but this is just my opinion. As to your question in general: On this site, it is recommended to ask one question at a time and to ask questions about specific problems, preferably by providing code of what has been done so far to show the specific issue. You already point to possible solutions for some of your sub-questions, so it would maybe a good idea to show what you've got so far and where you got stuck with exactly.

Comment: XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are compilers such as PDFLaTeX. A lot of commands are the same, but some are different, especially those concerning fonts. You should familiarize yourself with these [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/47927) and/or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/47927). With both compilers, you can easily load fonts that are installed on your system, which is probably a good idea if you want to use Calibri in your document. I would suggest that you first try to get the fonts to work and only then address the bibliography issue in a separate question.

Comment: First at all, I appreciate your opinion about that font @JasperHabicht, but that is just not the point. Is a commanded instrucction for my thesis, so must be it.
And its been a while since the last time I posted here, but is good to get some rules refreshed.

The reason I've made a mixed post is because I read others posts with the Calibri problem, I didn't understood what's LauLatex or how to set it up, but in some of those posts also got new problems with margins, aligneation and bibliography after that change... However that Calibri setting is a must.

Comment: I assumed that it is a requirement. It is still difficult to help you with a concise answer, because your question is quite broad. Maybe look for examples on this site that show how to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to load fonts. If you have a full TeX installation on your computer (which I assume if you use TeXStudio and PDFLaTeX), you should be able to [switch the compiler](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235245) easily. As noted above, some packages can't be used with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. But since you did not provide any code, it is hard to tell what should be changed in your document exactly.

Comment: Anyway, I'll check thos post you say too. Might be useful.

Comment: Your requirements are from Peru, and I have a somehow 90% working thesis here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/xwcdkjfmfvym , but its for University of Piura. Feel free to use it as a base.

Comment: Thanks, @ManuelMerino. I'll check it as it seems to come handy. Basically, once I managed to attach ExLaTeX to that document (what a discover such those magic comments), I've started testing some basics format commands and more or less is working.

Anyway, I'll update this post to improve it and showing on my try.

Comment: @Suiron, that document already implements some things:
- Uses Calibri similar typeface: Carlito in 12pt.
- Already uses 10pt for page numbering and centered. If you need to move it to the footer, change the command `\fancyhead` to `\fancyfoot` (see `fancyhdr` documentation)
- Inter paragraph spacing of 6pt is already implemented and 1.2 line-spacing
- Does have a external pdf as a cover page and watermark.
- Figures and Tables use APA like styles.
- Uses `biblatex` using apa7 style.
- Page margins with `geometry` package (already loaded with 2.5 all margin specification)

Comment: @ManuelMerino I'm checking right now your document to fix numbering size and definitely will check it for biblio and APA issues. It's going to be extremely handy. Thanks!

Comment: Point 4 is already fixed thanks to @ManuelMerino doc. Just changed `\rfoot{\fontsize{10}{12} \centering\thepage}` by `\fancyfoot[C]{fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\thepage}`. I have no idea why command \selectfont is necessary, but another goal achieved.

Answer (score 1):

One tweak is that TeX uses a different definition of “pt” than most other software, and calls 1/72" a “big point” (`bp`).  In that context, “12-point” probably means 1/6", like in PostScript and Microsoft Word.  That should be specified as [`12bp`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/setting-a-document-in-ms-word-12pt-12bp) in LaTeX.

So, for instance,

```
\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}
```

You might consider using Koma-Script.  The standard classes have only a few, rigid size options.  Either `\documentclass{scrartcl}` pr `\usepackage{scrextend}` accepts the option `fontsize=12bp`, though.