# Font Aptos how to use in Latex/Texstudio

Tags: fonts, fontspec

The people in my department have decided to use the font Aptos which is a MS Word font. They use MS Word for writing mathematical documents. Yes, that's correct. I now need to use the font Aptos in latex. I use Texstudio and the exam class. I also have access to MS Office which I get for free, but never use, but if I can't fix this issue I will have to use it.  Please help me, and explain how I get latex to compile with the Aptos font. I used  \usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Aptos} and it didn't work. I think I may have to download the Aptos font from somewhere if so where can I downlaod it safely

Comment: Aptos should be installed on your computer as it comes with MS Word on Windows. You can check that it is installed properly by starting MS Word and looking whether the font shows up in the font menu. If the font does not show up in the font menu in MS Word, you should still be able to install it easily. If it does show up, you should be able to use `\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{Aptos}` and compile with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX on your machine. If this does not work, please show the error you got in your log.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response error is as follows:Package fontspec Error: The font "Aptos" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Aptos" cannot be found.
Package fontspec Error: The font "Aptos" cannot be found.
Font \TU/Aptos(0)/m/n/10=name:Aptos:mode=node;language=dflt;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
Unknown language 'latin'. Hyphenation patterns for(lipsum) 'english' will be used instead.  I used tools commands LauLaTex

Comment: Another error using XeLatex Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C
:\Users\Jon\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Couldn't open `Apt.cfg' hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4) and loads more don't understand any of this

Comment: `The font "Aptos" cannot be found` means that the font is probably not installed on your machine or it is installed in a format that LaTeX cannot parse. Did you check whether the font is installed on your system?

Comment: I've downloaded the Aptos font package it's a zip file form Techspot. Can I do anything with this to get Texstudio to comple with Aptos

Comment: Jasper how do I check whether it's installed on my machine. Do I do control panel, Appearance and Personalisation then Fonts because it is not showing there.

Comment: If you have the font file at hand, just right-click on the file and select "install" or double-click on the font file and click on "Install" in the preview window. Make sure that you install all font files you need (Regular, Bold, Italic ...). You should also be able to just place the font files in the working directory where your `.tex` file sits.

Comment: Aside: The other part of the message, about 'latin', will be fixed if you install package `hyphen-latin`. That message often appears if you use the `lipsum` package to generate fake latin text, without latin support.

Answer (score 0):

The new default font in the Microsoft Suite is Aptos. To get the Aptos font in Texstudio, you first have to install it on your machine. For this, do the following:

1. Download the Aptos font package from Techspot ([link](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/7566-aptos-font.html)).
2. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQK0lDnfjjI) shows you how to install fonts on Windows 10.
   A similar process can be followed for Windows 11; just click install, instead of install all users for Windows 10. You have to highlight everything.

To get the font to work with Texstudio:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Aptos}
```

All formulas in MS Word use Cambria math so you need this as well:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
```

Now you need to put the [magic comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235245/where-do-i-find-the-xelatex-engine-on-texstudio)

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
```

and compile in the usually way, don't use the Tools/command/XelaTex that doesn't work.